# Full height two column and header with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

I'm in trouble with a web page that I would like to get with a two column that are full height and a header with a navbar. But I cannot obtain the effect because the columns scroll under the header.

This is my html

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-lg fixed-top py-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="~/images/icona-64.png" width="32" height="32" alt="brand">
            brand
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-list-4" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-list-4">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="~/images/icona-64.png" width="40" height="40" class="rounded-circle">
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dashboard</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit Profile</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log Out</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="appContainer" class="container-fluid d-flex px-0" style="min-height: 100%;">
        <div class="dpPanelSx bg-info vh-100">Panel Sx</div>
        <div class="dpPanelDx vh-100">Panel Dx</div>
    </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
```

The CSS

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
/* set custom color for the nav bar*/
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #034c67; /*#213B52;*/
}
    /* change the brand and text color */
    .navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-text {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    }
    /* change the link color */
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    }
    /* change the color of active or hovered links */
    .navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
    .navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .dpPanelSx {
        flex: 1;
    }

    .dpPanelDx {
        flex: 1;
    }
```

And I added a javascript to force the height of the column to the height of the body

```
$(document).ready(setupApplication);

function setupApplication() {
    // set the containter size
    resizeContainer();

    // setup eventlistener
    $(window).resize(resizeContainer);
}

function resizeContainer() {
    var viewH = document.body.clientHeight;
    var viewW = $(window).width();
    var headHeight = $('nav').height();

    console.log('body: ' + document.body.clientHeight);
    console.log('window: ' + window.innerHeight);
    try {
        $('body').css('padding-top', headHeight);
        // $('#appContainer').height(viewH - headHeight);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

I definitely not able to obtain my desidered effect.
I need a page that is full size height, can you help please?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need the javascript to achieve it. I have removed `fixed-top` on your `nav`.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}


/* set custom color for the nav bar*/

.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #034c67;
  /*#213B52;*/
}


/* change the brand and text color */

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}


/* change the link color */

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}


/* change the color of active or hovered links */

.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.dpPanelSx {
  flex: 1;
}

.dpPanelDx {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-lg py-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="~/images/icona-64.png" width="32" height="32" alt="brand"> brand
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-list-4" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-list-4">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <img src="~/images/icona-64.png" width="40" height="40" class="rounded-circle">
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dashboard</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit Profile</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log Out</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="appContainer" class="container-fluid d-flex px-0" style="min-height: 100%;">
    <div class="dpPanelSx bg-info vh-100">Panel Sx</div>
    <div class="dpPanelDx bg-success vh-100">Panel Dx</div>
  </div>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the page scrolls up and the nav bar disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to create 2 columns on your page. You can implement these to your codes.
Changes in HTML:

```
<div id="appContainer" class="container-fluid d-flex px-0">
    <div class="dpPanelSx bg-info vh-50">Panel Sx</div>
    <div class="dpPanelDx vh-50">Panel Dx</div>
</div>
```

Changes in CSS(Colors were added just to see the columns):

```
.container-fluid {
    columns: auto;
    columns: 2;
    height: 100%;
}

.dpPanelSx {
    column-width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
}

.dpPanelDx {
    column-width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
}
```